# Postgres database connectivity issues when using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize the REST api written in golang, but having troubles connecting to postgres database (the app works fine without docker). Below are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: test_db
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
  my-go-app:
      restart: always
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        context: .
      environment:
        # Postgres Details
        DB_HOST: postgres
        DB_DRIVER: postgres
        DB_USER: postgres
        DB_PASSWORD: 1234
        DB_NAME: test_db
        DB_PORT: 5432
        # APP details
        APP_PROTOCOL: http
        APP_HOST: localhost
        APP_PORT: 10000
        ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
      ports:
        - 10000:10000
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

Database properties: host = "localhost", port = 5432, user = "postgres", password="1234", dbname="test_db" (all specified in docker-compose.yml). App itself runs on port 10000

When running `docker up` and `docker-compose up --build` I'm getting `sql: database is closed error`

```
Starting rest_db_my-go-app_1 ... done
Attaching to rest_db_postgres_1, rest_db_my-go-app_1
my-go-app_1  | 2021/04/02 12:54:07 Connection Failed to Open
my-go-app_1  | 2021/04/02 12:54:07 Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:10000/
my-go-app_1  | 2021/04/02 12:54:07 Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
my-go-app_1  |
my-go-app_1  | (/app/main.go:185) 
my-go-app_1  | [2021-04-02 12:54:07]  sql: database is closed 
postgres_1   |
postgres_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1   |
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:15.807 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit   
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:15.808 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:15.808 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:15.815 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:15.831 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-02 12:02:14 UTC
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:15.837 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:25.830 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:25.834 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:25.835 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 32) exited with exit code 1
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:25.835 UTC [27] LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1   | 2021-04-02 12:02:25.862 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

How to solve this database connectivity issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: `depends_on` does not guarantee that DB is ready to accept connections. Log your app errors. You may see that you try to connect before DB is ready. Implement connection retry in app or add custom health check in docker

Comment: Even when I start with the db docker-compose up -d postgres the problem still persists

Comment: You've forgotten to add your volume to the postgres service. I don't think this will solve the problem, but worth adding it in.

Comment: What's actually providing the database configuration, the database-related environment variables in `docker-compose.yml` or the "database properties" in the following prose?  (As far as your application container is concerned, `localhost` is the application container and not the database container or the containing host.)

Comment: Connection to database is made in main.go with db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", psqlInfo) where host="localhost". should I replace it with "postgres"(name of the db container)?

Comment: @HelenGrey yes. You should replace localhost with postgres. Cause you can't reach other containers through localhost.

Comment: @AlekseiBelezeko did that; "sql: database is closed" error is gone, but I'm still getting "database system was shut down" and right after that "database system is ready to accept connections" in log

Comment: @HelenGrey without your code it's hard to say what's wrong.